# Rails 5 before_action with method parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Is it possible to do something like the following?

```rb
class PageController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_page, <send parameter `with_includes` to `set_page` as boolean based on conditions>

  ...

  private
  
  def set_page(with_includes = true)
    @page = default ? Page.includes(:child) : Page
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to call `before_action` with a lambda function:

```
 before_action -> { set_page(your_condition_here) }
```

Or with a block

```
before_action do
  set_page(your_condition_here)
end
```